# Как проверить объект на отсуствие в нем свойств с undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
arr=[]

  $.each(data,function(key,val){
             if(typeof(val)!="undefined"){ 
                arr.push(val.info) //проверяю объект но в него всёравно попадают undefined
            }  
    });
console.log(arr)//arr[item1,item2,undefined,item4.....]
```

Comment: проверяете `val` а складываете `gid`? где конкретно вы получаете undefined?

Comment: поменяв gid, на info, на самом деле ничего не поменялось, как проверялся объект val. так и проверяется, как складывается его поле, так и складывается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы заносите в массив `val.info`, то его и нужно проверять на `undefined`:

```
if (typeof val !== "undefined" && typeof val.info !== "undefined") { 
    arr.push(val.info);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`hasOwnPropety`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) проверяет наличие самого свойства

Comment: пишу и всё попрежнему
    
       ` $.each(data.response,function(key,val){
      if(!val.hasOwnProperty("undefined")){  
                arr.push(val.info)
             }  
       });
      `

Comment: @test_q_1, естественно, в вашем примере проверяется наличие поля _undefined_ в объекте _data_, а в массив кладешь _val.info_. Определись какое именно поле тебе надо собирать и его проверяй